# Shortestpath with complex criteria, is it possible in any graph DBMS

Tags: neo4j, orientdb, arangodb

Right now I'm using Neo4j and solved the task from the wrong side.
At first I get `allShortestPaths` and then search for right ones within them with java.
Of course this way cannot guarantee results even if they exist.
So, I'm searching for any graph DBMS that can natively search what I need.

Datamodel is simple:

- Nodes: no properties except identifying number
- Relations: 1 property with **double** value

To make it clear - it is a list of organisations and shares which they own of each other (i.e. property=percentage >0 <=100).

criteria when going through path is:

- If next relation is 50++ the node is included (path continues)
- If next relation is less, then 50, but all nodes already in path own
  50+ of this node, then still the path continues

This means that algorithm should calculate not only the relations of the path itself, but "side" relations (preferably not always, but only when "next relation" is 50--).

And last, but not the least: it is expected to have performance of native shortestpath (ie several milliseconds on 18mln nodes + 40mln relations) or close. Not hours or even minutes. Right now shortestpath finds paths with 30-40-50 hops in milliseconds, that's amazing. Playing with relation value I'm able to get shortestpaths of several lengths in few seconds. But this is not ideal solution.

I'm not Neo4j expert (yet :), from what I've discovered so far - performance of `allsSortestPaths` is rather thick thing. Adding extra criteria can drop performance from milliseconds to hours. That is not acceptable :( Path length of 10++ is also a must.

I guess, that I want too much, but still, any hints, ideas, solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

For small data-sets, I would just trust Cypher to handle it with some WHERE conditions (easiest solution, least efficient)

The next best solution (if you can), is to "pre-compile" the solution. If you can frame the problem in such a way that a few ledger nodes or relationships can store the information you need, and that updating these ledgers is easier than completely recompiling the solution, than this will be the best way to store and retrieve the information (since on read, you just need to pull up one node or relationship).

But maybe you can't possibly simplify the solution, and you just **have** to do the complex traversal. Cypher is good about this, but it is blind to what is in the database, and can't exploit facts that you would know. In that case (for the best performance) you will want to use the [Traversal API](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorial-traversal) (there is also the [Java Core](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world) API for Neo4J, but the Traversal API is much easier and only negligibly slower)